# Distance that a broken block can be collected by you

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been working on one of those "motion control traps" searching for more ways to put them to use.  I'm kind of confused now, however.  Walking at the same level lets me collect it, but not above or below.  I can't seem to understand how far and where I have to be to collect it.  Any exact details?  The Minecraft Wiki didn't seem to contain anything about it.

Comment: Could you explain or provide a link to just what you mean by "motion control trap"?

Comment: Would think it is some kind of spawn trap or a cacti farm.

Comment: @Fambida Here is a youtube Vid:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wBpW6lwou7I&feature=related

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Before:

[image: before]

## After:

[image: after]

Although the picture doesn't show it, the character rotation has *nothing* do do with the bounding box for gathering. Additionally, moving laterally evenly picks up items, so it seems that there's a 3m×3m box surrounding the character within which items will be gathered.

<sub>Dropping that much wool dispersed took quite a while, I may add more screenshots for vertical tests later.</sub>

Comment: I really like the way that you tested it.  So would it be safe to say that anything 1.5 meters away is probably grabbable?

Comment: @DalexL, I'm hesitant to agree with that statement, because it implies a rounded radius. I would say that your character has a hitbox of 1m² and that it has a "gathering" box of 3m² both centered around the character.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense.  But 1.5 in front, back, and on the sides I'm assuming.  That's all I really need to know.  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

Of my experience with minecraft, I would be saying about 1 meter (1 block) would be the distance at which a mined block (not experience) will be "sucked up" by you.

And 1 meter is of any part of your body (your body technically holds 2 meter high by 1x1 meter.)